# ActiveRecord OR for existing scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord, arel

I have an existing model with a set of complex scopes:

```
scope :test1 , where(gift: true)
scope :test2 , lambda {|time| where("last_created_at > ?", time)}
scope :test3 , where(approved: true)
```

I can than do something like

```
User.test1.test2.test3.all
```

Now, say I want to append a global OR scope to this. i.e. select all this (test1 + test2 +test) OR when user is an admin (not working code, of course):

```
scope :admin , where("OR admin=", true)
```

Is there any way to do this with existing scope, or does this require an all new rewrite with AREL or plain SQL?

One hack I found for this is :

```
  scope :admin , where("1=1) OR admin=1 AND (1=1", true)
```

But, I mean, can this get any uglier than that.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ARel, scopes are always connected with `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

As a weird hack, the scope I suggest above does work.
However , as a plain solution, it seems that easiest approach is to perform two separated queries and concat the active record results.
I used the concat option, I think it also makes the code readable, with probably negligible, if any, impact to performances.

```
scope :test1 , where(gift: true)
scope :test2 , lambda {|time| where("last_created_at > ?", time)}
scope :test3 , where(approved: true)
scope :admin , where(admin: true)
data1 = User.test1.test2.test3.all
data2 = User.admin.all

(data1 + data2)
```